# How to solve Error in as.vector (x, mode) : cannot coerce type 'closure' to vector of type 'any'

Tags: r

##### First function

```
m <- 50
l <- 50
initial1 <- function(m, l) {
  sample(c("S", "I"), size=m*l, prob=c(0.9, 0.1), replace=TRUE)
}
```

##### Second Function

```
plot_infection <- function(initial1) {
  sir_colors <- c("White", "Grey", "Red")
  x1 <- matrix(x, nrow=m)
  x1
  z <- matrix(0, nrow=m, ncol=l)
  z[x == "I"] <- 1
  image(z, col=sir_colors)
}

plot_infection(initial1)
```

Comment: You might want to get into the habit of a cleaner code style, hope you don't mind my edit. Consider to consult an R style guide like this one: https://jef.works/R-style-guide/

Answer (score 1):

You need to call the function `initial1`. Apart from that there are few variables which are not called correctly. Try -

```
m=50
l=50

initial1=function(m,l){
  sample(c("S","I"), size=m*l, prob=c(0.9,0.1), replace=TRUE)
}

plot_infection= function(initial1){
  sir_colors=c("White", "Grey", "Red")
  x1=matrix(initial1,nrow=m)
  z=matrix(0, nrow=m, ncol=l)
  z[x1=="I"]=1
  image(z, col = sir_colors)
}

plot_infection(initial1(m, l))
```

[image]